# OnetimeRequest don't work with initialDelay

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

androidx 2.0.0; Oneplus 3T; H2os;

When I use `enqueueUniqueWork()` with a non-delay workRequest, the work begins correctly; But When I use `enqueueUniqueWork()` with a 1-minute-delay workRequest, the work don't work even after 20 minutes. Even after one day!

I tried the [sample code](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-workmanager), in that project, I set a initialDelay on the first cleanup request, that works. But when I enqueue a workRequest in SelectImageActivity, that fails again. What I mean `fail`, is the request worked sometimes, but sometimes it don't. I can't get the point.

`enqueue workRequest`

```
OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(UpdateWorker.class)
                .setInitialDelay(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build();
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniqueWork("com.pkg.onetime_work", ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, oneTimeWorkRequest);
Timber.d("Work scheduled in MainActivity.start");
```

`Worker`

```
public Result doWork() {
        Timber.d("UpdateWorker.doWork");
        return Result.SUCCESS;
     }
```

I want to run a job after one minutes, but the workRequest did't run even after one day.

Comment: And test this is so waste of time, I tried three days on this, is there some big person can help me ? THANK YOU very much!

Comment: Does it work on a stock Android device/emulator?  This may be a problem specific to your device and whitelisting.

Comment: @SumirKodes I'm sorry, my phone screen was broken, I'm fixing it. I'll test this after my phone screen fixed.

Comment: please allow auto start permission in order to run background OneTimeWorker in chinese devices.